# Crash reporting for java

Tags: java, reporting-services, crash

Do you know any good crash reporting systems for Java or any open source projects which use a crash reporting system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash dump is just a text file.  You could write a script which repeatedly runs your problem and mail you/notifies you of any new crash dumps.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from simple 
In case you want to report errors and exceptions to user in Java Swing Application htere is a nice library [zeus-jscl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeus-jscl/) that has several useful components:

**gr.zeus.ui.JMessage** - Displays simple messages and the stacktrace of an exception and more
**gr.zeus.ui.JConsolePane** - A java console to replace the command line window. Redirects the stdout and stderr etc.

This is sent nowhere it just locally convenient.

All of this brings me to how handles unhanded exceptions that occur in the wild. NetBeans pops up this little dialog and asks you to send in your report. Once you do send it, it's almost magical, reports are queued, analyzed, associated to either a new report or an existing report and finally the generic reports are associated to an issue in IssueZilla and it does it all automatically. If the issue is fixed, it even tells you in which, upcoming or not, version it has been fixed.
from [here](http://codepimpsdotorg.blogspot.com/2008/08/netbeans-exception-reporting.html)

You can download sources of NetBeans and rip off what you need. [Read here how](http://www.netbeans.org/community/sources/)